# how to test for true, when value may not be proper boolean

Tags: javascript

Is there a function or statement I can use to check for true/false that I could be getting from php, or html, or some source that would provide a true or false value that javascript would not understand as boolean. So I could check for the string true or boolean true or a 1 value (which php returns for true, I think..)

So like:

```
    var trueVal = true;
    if ( trueVal == true || trueVal === true || trueVal == "true" || trueVal == "TRUE" || trueVal == "1" || trueVal == 1 ) {

    //

    }
```

Does this make sense? Is there a much easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What would the value be for false? Same dilemma? If not, you could check for it NOT being 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you can make sure the `true` is passed correctly, then it could be a lot easier:

```
if( trueVal)
```

The only time this would be a problem is if you had the string `"false"` or `"0"`, but that can be fixed:

```
if( trueVal && !trueVal.toString().match(/^(false|0)$/i))
```

Comment: i really don't have control over how `true` is passed, as that comes from various sources..

Comment: This treats `"0"` and `"FALSE"` as truthy.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I meant to put `i`, not `g`... As for `"0"`, I'll add that too.

Comment: Updated to convert integers to strings before attempting to regex them.

Comment: really great! seems to work in just about every conceivable situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is a value that looks like the word "true" in some form or a non-zero integer, convert it to a string and then check whether it looks like the word true or a non-zero integer.

```
function isPHPTrue(x) {
  x = String(x);
  if (/^(true|[+-]?0*[1-9][0-9]*)$/i.test(x)) { return true; }
  if (/^(false|[+-]?0+)$/i.test(x)) { return false; }
  throw new Error('Not obviously true or false: ' + x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know much about regular expressions. Is that searching a potentially long string for `true` anywhere inside?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EMh6Z/ this gives me either `true` or `false`, and then always has the error about it being not obviously one or the other

Comment: @thomas, Your jsfiddle always raises an error because you replaced `return` with `alert`.  `return` ends the function call.  When you use `alert` instead, it does not end the function call so proceeds to throw an error.

Comment: @thomas, no that regex is not searching within a long string for true.  The `^` and `$` anchor the string so that the whole text must be "true" or a non-zero integer.  The `i` at the end makes it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't a "general" way to do this, like a sort-of meta-boolean check function, but you can sort-of decrease the number of comparisons:

```
trueVal="1";
if(trueVal*1==1||trueVal.toLowerCase()=="true"){
    //do stuff
}
```

The `trueVal*1` takes `"1"`, `1` and `true`; `trueVal.toLowerCase()=="true"` takes `"true"`, `"tRuE"` and all uppercase/lowercase variants.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: how does `trueVal*1` deal with `true`? Thanks!

Comment: @thomas `true==1` gives `true`, so `true*1==1*1==1==true` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToBoolean(input) {
    return input.toLowerCase() == "true" || input == 1;
}

// And to test this works:

console.log(convertToBoolean("TRUE"));  //true, boolean
console.log(convertToBoolean("true"));  //true, boolean
console.log(convertToBoolean("false")); //false, boolean
console.log(convertToBoolean("1"));     //true, boolean
console.log(convertToBoolean(0));       //false, boolean
// and of course...
console.log(convertToBoolean(true));    //true, boolean
```